# Restart activity on command received from Firebase

Tags: android, android-activity, timertask, non-static

I'm trying to restart my main activity on a command received from Firebase. Ive managed to make it work but in MainActivity class has a TimerTask and in order to call the Stop function from my Firebase class I have to make a new instance of the MainActivity Class. This will also create a new instance of the timer. The command will stop the timer (the new initiated one) but the old one keeps running in the background. How can I call the stop function in the MainActivity withouth creating a new instance. Its a non-static function so I cannot call it from a static context.

Here's my Code snipet if it helps.

```
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String msg = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Log.v("test", "FB msg is: " + msg);
        if (msg.equals(COMMAND)) {
             Intent i = new Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this, DashboardActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
            dashboardActivity.stopTimer();


           // SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).storeTimer("false");


        } else {
            Log.v("test", "unknown");
        }
    }
```

Ultimately, I want to send a command from Firebase that will force my MainActivity to restart completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used BroadcastReceiver and it worked. Follow this example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
new dashboardActivity().stopTimer();
```

if there's a error then use

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new dashboardActivity().stopTimer();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: That will create a new instance of the DashboardActivity. which will create a new timer and the old timer will keep working in the background.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to restart your activity, use this code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You cannot use finish(); from another class. Also my stop function is in a service class.